# Write-Output Failing Inside Foreach Loop - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and I am wondering why this function doesn't work the way I want it too.  The following function uncomments line in the hosts file of the computer specified. It works great!  But I want the ability to output each line to the screen using a Write-Output and get the variable and store it in another array.  This Write-Output doesn't do anything and I cannot add it to the array.  Why?  The above Write-Output works just fine.

```
function UnCommentHostsFile($ip){

   Write-Output "This Write-Output Works!"

   $hosts = $hosts | Foreach {

       #This part of the function works great!
       if ($_ -match $regex + $ip){
           $_.replace("#", "")

           #This is where I want to add it to an array and write-output but I can't.
       } 
       else {
           $_
       }

       #This does not output!
       Write-Output $_
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, when you do this:

```
$hosts = $hosts | Foreach {...}
```

everything that is output to the pipeline within that `foreach` script block is going to get re-directed to the variable `$hosts`.

`Write-Output` writes to the pipeline, and you're doing it within that script block.

If you want to explicitly write to the screen, use `Write-Host`, or `Write-Verbose`.

Comment: This didn't work.  I tried putting Write-Host, Write-Output, and Write-Verbose.  Nothing is outputting to the screen but it is still correctly writing to the file.

Comment: Nothing.  Nothing gets written to the screen in any of the three cases.  If I place the Write- statement inside the if statement it does not get run.  If I place Write-Host here my original Write-Output was it prints out every line in the file.  I only want the lines that have been changed.

Comment: Are you sure any of it matched the If condition?

Comment: Yes, cause the file changes.  Every time I run it, it comments out about 10 lines in the hosts.file.  The next time I run it i switch it and it comments out a different set of IP's.  This is very strange.

Comment: It is strange indeed.  Running that with test data, I get it written to the console  If I set $VerbosePreference to Continue I get Verbose console output along with it.

Comment: I just set $VerbosePreference = "Continue" and looked at my regex and I got it to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the Write-Output. Leave it as an object, and you can format that object however you want outside the function. I updated it so that for each line if it matches your regex it replaces # with nothing as you already had it, but I removed the Else clause because it was pointless. I changed `$_.replace("#", "")` to `$_ = $_.replace("#", "")` so that it actually updates the line in $Hosts instead of just echoing it. Then when all is said and done it outputs the entire $hosts updated lines and all.

```
function UnCommentHostsFile($ip){

   $hosts = $hosts | Foreach {

       #This part of the function works great!
       if ($_ -match $regex + $ip){
           $_ = $_.replace("#", "")

           #This is where I want to add it to an array and write-output but I can't.
       } 

       #This does not output!
   }
   $Hosts
}
```

Edit: When you call the function it should spit back whatever is in $Hosts, so it should output to the screen. No need to write-output or anything. It will show up on screen for the user, unless you are redirecting the output to something, in which case just add a bit to the pipe that prints it to the screen.

Comment: I need to write to the screen, some non technical people will be using this script, and save it to an array to run operations on specific entries.   $_.replace("#", "") worked just fine and your code works too.